# Can't login with session id in Flash builder for force.com application

Tags: api, soap, flex3, salesforce, visualforce

I have simple Flex for Force application and I want to embed it into VisualForce page. I've done everything as described in tutorials and tested it against DE, but I get INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Please see the code below and tell me where I'm wrong...

My VF page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
    <apex:flash src="{!$Resource.bug2_swf}" width="100%" height="100%"
                flashvars="session_id={!$Api.Session_ID}&server_url={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_200}"/>
</apex:page>
```

My MXML file

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:TraceTarget includeCategory="true"
                   includeLevel="true"
                   includeTime="true"
                   level="{LogEventLevel.INFO}"
                   filters="{['com.salesforce.*']}"/>

    <flexforforce:F3WebApplication id="app"
                                   statusChanged="statusChangedHandler(event)"
                                   loginComplete="loginCompleteHandler(event)"
                                   loginFailed="loginFailedHandler(event)"
                                   sessionExpired="sessionExpiredHandler(event)"
                                   />
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.salesforce.events.LoginFaultEvent;
        import com.salesforce.events.LoginResultEvent;
        import com.salesforce.events.SessionExpiredEvent;
        import com.salesforce.events.StatusChangedEvent;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.logging.LogEventLevel;
        import mx.managers.CursorManager;
        import mx.rpc.Responder;

        private var _username : String;
        private var _password : String;

        [Bindable]
        private var _status : String = "";

        protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            var obj:Object = this.parameters;

            trace(obj.session_id);
            trace(obj.server_url);

            app.serverUrl = obj.server_url;
            app.loginBySessionId(obj.session_id);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the session you are passing to Flex.

{!$Api.Session_ID} returns the Visualforce session, but {!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_200} points to the "salesforce" domain. You need to get the "salesforce" session like this:

and have a property in your controller/extension like this:

public String SessionId { 
 get { 
  return UserInfo.getSessionId(); 
 } 
}

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much! It works. I really should post my questions here instead of creating cases in SF partner portal :).